# Jquery load default element

Tags: jquery, html, css

hi I'm trying to load a default class on page load, I have wrote the following code but need the it to load .pu1 content item on page load before hovering over other links, then remove once you hover over other links:
I'm lost on how to do this or what to search for??

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pua1').hover(function () {
        $('.pu1').show();
    }, function () {
        $(".pu1").hide();
    });
    $('.pua2').hover(function () {
        $('.pu2').show();
    }, function () {
        $(".pu2").hide();
    });
    $('.pua3').hover(function () {
        $('.pu3').show();
    }, function () {
        $(".pu3").hide();
    });
    $('.pua4').hover(function () {
        $('.pu4').show();
    }, function () {
        $(".pu4").hide();
    });
});
```

CSS Code:

```
.pua1, .pua2, .pua3, .pua4 {  }
.pu1, .pu2, .pu3, .pu4 {
      display:none;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="links"> 
    <a href="#" class="pua1">link one</a>
    <a href="#" class="pua2">link two</a>
    <a href="#" class="pua3">link three</a> 
    <a href="#" class="pua4">link four</a>
</div>
<div id="text">
    <div class="pu1">
        <p>text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pu2">
        <p>text 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pu3">
        <p>text 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pu4">
        <p>text 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="images">
    <div class="pu1">
        <img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344">
    </div>
    <div class="pu2">
        <img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344">
    </div>
    <div class="pu3">
        <img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344">
    </div>
    <div class="pu4">
        <img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @gdoron hm.. well I highlighted the code and ctrl K to indent it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your html to decrease Javascript complexity. I also assumed you didn't want to hide everything at a given time, because you've got it starting with `.pu1` visible.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQuQD/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pua').hover(function () {
        $('.pu').hide();
        $('.'+$(this).attr("data-display-class")).show();
    }, function () { });

    $('.pu1').show();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="links"> 
    <a href="#" data-display-class="pu1"  class="pua">link one</a>
    <a href="#" data-display-class="pu2"  class="pua">link two</a>
    <a href="#" data-display-class="pu3"  class="pua">link three</a> 
    <a href="#" data-display-class="pu4" class="pua">link four</a>
</div>
<div id="text">
    <div class="pu1 pu">
        <p>text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pu2 pu">
        <p>text 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pu3 pu">
        <p>text 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pu4 pu">
        <p>text 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="images">
    <div class="pu1 pu">
        <img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344">
    </div>
    <div class="pu2 pu">
        <img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344">
    </div>
    <div class="pu3 pu">
        <img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344">
    </div>
    <div class="pu4 pu">
        <img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this shows the .pu1 elements but they remain there when I hover over other 3 links before hovering over link one, then it disappears on hover on another links after hovering over link one..

Comment: `$('.pu').hide();` should hide `pu1` too...if you added `pu` as a class like `<div class="pu1 pu">`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you simply tried this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ....

    $('.pu1').show();
})
```

**Edit :** Added `$('.pu').hide();` to all hover's functions and the class `pu` to all div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pua1').hover(function(){
        $('.pu').hide();
        $('.pu1').show();
    }, function() {
        $(".pu1").hide();
    });

    $('.pua2').hover(function(){
        $('.pu').hide();
        $('.pu2').show();
    }, function() {
        $(".pu2").hide();
    });

    $('.pua3').hover(function(){
        $('.pu').hide();
        $('.pu3').show();
    }, function() {
        $(".pu3").hide();
    });

    $('.pua4').hover(function(){
        $('.pu').hide();
        $('.pu4').show();
    }, function() {
        $(".pu4").hide();
    });

    $('.pu1').show();
});
</script>

<div id="links"> <a href="#" class="pua1">link one</a>
    <a href="#" class="pua2">link two</a>
    <a href="#" class="pua3">link three</a>
    <a href="#" class="pua4">link four</a>
</div>
<div id="text">
    <div class="pu pu1"><p>text 1</p></div>
    <div class="pu pu2"><p>text 2</p></div>
    <div class="pu pu3"><p>text 3</p></div>
    <div class="pu pu4"><p>text 4</p></div>
</div>
<div id="images">
    <div class="pu pu1"><img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344"></div>
    <div class="pu pu2"><img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344"></div> 
    <div class="pu pu3"><img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344"></div>
    <div class="pu pu4"><img src="x/img/cut_03.jpg" width="407" height="344"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @smokey yes but when you hover over other links the .pu1 content stays there knocking the other content below it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('#links > a').on('hover', function(){
    var index = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.pu'+ index.substring(3)).show();
});

$('#links > a').on('mouseleave', function(){
    var index = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.pu'+ index.substring(3)).hide();
});
```

And see this [jSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQuQD/4/)